# What are the benefits of digitizing the government?

Tags: government, technology

> Schools with outdated computers. Health authorities relying on fax
> machines. Town offices that offer few or none of their services online
> — that's the reality in Germany in 2021.
>
> Eight years after German Chancellor Angela Merkel was famously
> ridiculed for referring to the internet as "uncharted territory," the
> response to the coronavirus pandemic exposed how digital shortcomings
> continue to plague Germany's public sector — perplexing observers
> around the world.
>
> Why, they wonder, can't Europe's richest country modernize and
> digitize its administration?

https://www.dw.com/en/germany-and-digitalization-why-cant-europes-richest-country-get-up-to-speed/a-58273979

> Denmark, Finland and the Republic of Korea lead the 2022 digital
> government ranking of the 193 United Nations Member States, scoring
> the highest when it comes to the scope and quality of online services,
> the status of telecommunication infrastructure and existing human
> capacity. Runners-up are New Zealand, Sweden, Iceland, Australia,
> Estonia, the Netherlands, the United States, the United Kingdom,
> Singapore, the United Arab Emirates, Japan and Malta.

https://unric.org/en/denmark-finland-and-south-korea-top-the-2022-un-e-government-ranking/

The report doesn't tell us what might be the benefits of digitizing the government. I thought that it would boost GDP, but Germany is significantly richer than other European countries, and is a leading exporter still, so I was wondering if there's any benefit at all of digitizing the government since the government is rarely efficiently run anyways.

Comment: "Government is inefficient" is almost never about the interaction with individual citizens (although many of them may feel it is).  It's rather more about the overall decision-making process (ie, getting a bill passed), which can't be substantially digitized in the first place.  That's not to say that digitization wouldn't bring savings, but effects on GDP are going to be limited to non-existent.  Also, GDP is likely the wrong measure here, since you'd likely be looking at some per-resident metric.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Personally, when I think about government inefficiency, I think of a big windowless office building in Virginia somewhere full of IRS drones typing away at keyboards, and that *can* be a significant expense. Whether that government expense shows up as lowered GDP (presumably from higher taxes) is much more difficult to nail down of course.

Comment: One problem with digitalization and Germany is the federal structure. Every federal state may implement it's own digital solution for a specific area. That may increase costs and introduce incompatibilities.

Comment: @Cadence - That depends entirely on what their actual task is; if it's manually tabulating taxes, then yes.  If they're performing manual review of automatically flagged accounts for audit, then no.  Just because you have a lot of people involved in the same task, doesn't mean it's inefficient or even something you want to automate (ie, normally you don't want to completely remove humans from some decision loops).

Comment: Digitizing the government makes it give better services to citizens. More information is accessible and quicker transactions. For example you can get an official document almost instantly by logging in to a government portal without physically going to the government building and waiting for people to attend you.

Comment: Wrt GDP, salaries used to pay people on bullshit jobs enter GDP just the same way as salaries to pay people who work efficiently. GDP is not a good surrogate for overall productivity. Private time citizens spend going to and waiting at some office is not counted in GDP - avoiding this is a huge improvement for personal life that is not measured at all by GDP.

Comment: Also improved efficiency does not necessarily lead to (say) lower taxes. Instead, we may "spend" gained efficiency on more detailed procedures, like the possibility to have more detailed statistics @Ventolinmono mentions. This may even cause the burocratic equivalent to feature creep.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution: my impression is that "federal structure" is a fashionable scape goat in many questions where we diagnose a lack of advance. However, Estonia and Finland have similar numbers of inhabitants as the German Länder of whom 2 have fewer citizens than Estonia and 5 have more than Finland. So I don't see why solutions at the Länder-level pursued by each Land would be more expensive (neither in total nor per capita) than the Finnish or Estonian solutions. Nor do I think any resulting incompatibilities would create more hassle than a paper-based status quo...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My day-job is in the business of digitizing the public administration in Germany. Undertaking this endeavor has several benefits for the government and the citizens:

- It speeds up processes. Working with physical files takes a lot more time than working with digital ones. They are faster to look up and can be accessed from anywhere. In some cases, processes can even be partially automatized. That means that processes can be completed faster and with less personnel.
- It improves access for citizens with disabilities. Many analog processes required people to come to a government office in person, which can be challenging or even impossible for some people. Digital processes can be done online from home.
- It improves transparency. Want to know the ratio of approved to rejected requests for social security benefits by municipality in the past 5 years? If all those requests with their status are in a SQL database, then that's really easy to find out. If that data is on paper in a hundred file cabinets? Not so much.

None of that does of course affect GDP in a direct and measurable way. The effect is more indirect.

- Faster processes do not just save money for the government (and by extension the citizens and companies who fund them with their tax money), they also save money for companies whose projects are blocked because they are waiting for a government office to do something.
- Access for citizens with disability might allow people to contribute to the economy who otherwise could not.
- Transparency uncovers corruption and improves the ability of citizens, companies and politicians to make informed decisions.

Comment: And the reasoning in the question is also flawed. Nobody knows how even more well people in Germany might live now if only they would have had a more digitized government already in the past.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Wait?,  Nobody knows how faster, more efficient and transparent government processes would improve the lives of the people?  Really?

Comment: @JMS At the very least it would only be an assumption, not a proof, because it didn't happen (yet). Sometimes the assumptions are very optimistic and as Philipp says some impacts are only indirectly on the GDP. That makes it probably not so simple to predict its impact. If you think it's simpler, just link to a suitable resource.

Comment: I'd add that with partially automated tasks, you don't always need to start processes while government workers are available for your request - for example, submitting a form over the weekend to be handled on the next business day, or retrieving a document you requested from the government at a time when the government buildings are closed.

Comment: Cool. Are you an external consultant, work in a company that does that or you work in a branch of government that does digitization?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution computerization of business processes isn’t a radical idea yielding imaginary benefits.  it’s been a multi billion dollar industry for decades.  Buuisnesses do it continuously.  If you want to run government more like businesses this would be one good way to do that.  Put it all online.

Comment: The improved access is more important for disabled people since it is disproportionately difficult for them to get to offices, but getting to offices during office hours is non-negligible hassle for other citizens as well. Even without disability, one easily spends an "overhead" of several hours of getting to some office and back and waiting for an in-person transaction that itself takes a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Digitization does have some cost-reduction benefits too, if the [UK government](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/digital-efficiency-report/digital-efficiency-report) is to be believed:

> For some government services, the average cost of a digital transaction is almost 20 times lower than the cost of a telephone transaction, about 30 times lower than the cost of postal transaction[ and about 50 times lower than a face-to-face transaction.

They also have some estimates of the expected savings from their current round of efforts of around £1.7 billion, but that's a bit meaningless unless you're familiar with their current level of digitization etc. But the point is that these savings can be tentatively quantified, even if they might not turn out quite like that in the aftermath.

And generally speaking you're quite wrong that richer countries don't have a higher digitization in the government sector (as well); because [they do](https://www.brookings.edu/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Digital-government.pdf):

[image]

Comment: The UN E index measures use of telecommunications equipment, which of course includes fax machines.

Comment: @DavidHammen: yes, only 1/3 of that index is based on on-line services, but still relevant enough.

Comment: @DavidHammen: BTW, it's possible to filter [their data](https://publicadministration.un.org/egovkb/Data-Center) to show just that 3rd, i.e. OSI, but there's not a lot of change for the point I'm making.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Yeah, for OSI alone it's easier for some middle income (per capita) countries to tie with rich countries, so e.g. Kazakhstan ties with the US, and China or Brazil tie with Sweden, while (ahem) India ties with Germany. So it may be the case that middle- and high-income countries are less delineated on OSI alone, but I don't have time right now to plot my own graph of OSI vs GDP-per-capita. The poorer countries [Africa etc.] however clearly are at the bottom on OSI too.

Comment: @DavidHammen: ... with some exceptions like  Rwanda (which ties with Germany/India).

Comment: While Germany is in OSI terms just below India and Rwanda, it is also in between Norway and Switzerland. Personally, while I'd like to see better online services here in Germany, I also see decided improvements (the most recent one I discovered is online vehicle registration - which is a huge improvement in avoiding "overhead time" for getting to the office and back and insane waiting times). Also I think it is *good* that countries like India and Rwanda nowadays offer online services to their citizens at a level similar to Norway, Germany and Switzerland.

Comment: Also, this is right now a very dynamic situation, and likely a tight race. 2020 - 2022, Germany climbed 15 ranks, Rwanda +47 (that is, they overtook a quarter of all countries!), while Norway and India dropped -20 and -18 (and my guess is that they did not get worse in absolute terms, but just improved more slowly than other countries).  1/4 of all countries moved 20 or more ranks up or down, half of the contries moved 10 or more ranks up or down. I guess this means that these statistics are right now a very noisy snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Does not the article you link to already answer your question?

It gives the following specific examples:

- "Schools with outdated computers." – this isn't even about whether digitization is good at all, it is just a matter of modern equipment.
- "Health authorities relying on fax machines." – it should be obvious that fax machines are less convenient and use more resources than computers do.
- "Town offices that offer few or none of their services online" – it is more convenient for all citizens (another answer specifically mentioned those with disabilities, but it is true for others too) if they can interact with the government online rather than having to show up somewhere in person.
- "People had problems working from home due to patchy internet connections. And across the country, schools lacked basic technology for remote learning." – those are of course pandemic-specific problems.

You talk about "boosting GDP", but why should that be the only goal? The examples listed are clear examples of citizens' and government workers' quality of life having room for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

> since the government is rarely efficiently run anyways

By whose standard? That of petty-bourgeois liberals, who typically struggle to keep their own small business on track and their simple account books in balance?

I reject the idea that government is usually inefficient. Usually, it has overheads owing to the need for things done at massive scale to keep working come hell or highwater, and to control to a reasonable degree the kind of corruption and arbitrariness that permeates the everyday activity of the private sector.

> if there's any benefit at all of digitizing the government

There obviously are benefits to applying computers to government clerical activity, just as there are in the private sector.

Most government services were largely "digitised" decades ago. "Digitisation" just being a buzzword for the more common notion of "computerisation".

What's changed substantially since these previous computerisations is technology. The juiciest fruits in government were computerised well before the internet, and before telecoms had advanced to the point it has today, where the average connection to a single residential home now has more bandwidth than some whole telephone exchanges did 20 years ago.

The ubiquity of personal computers and internet connections, and the perceived overall resilience of the system, now makes it feasible not only for governments to perform internal processing with computers (which they have been doing for many decades), but to accept inputs and provide outputs to the public using internet alone.

The benefit of this is basically to extend the scope of computerisation. The private sector has led this, with retail shopping and the administration of many private services now done through the internet.

A main downside is that computerisation often enables and begets additional complexity, so that previously simple activities will be designed more complicated in a way that was once unthinkable.

Another downside is that the initial engineering of these systems is often extremely expensive, and so is their re-engineering, and this can make them extremely difficult to change (because the justification for change has to be enough to overcome the high threshold of costs associated with myriad expert engineers revisiting all its workings). Therefore, computerised systems are almost constantly sliding into obsolescence and a misfit with their purpose.

A third downside is that typically it is the consumer who pays, in unwaged time and effort, for performing more administration via more complicated computer interfaces.

A fourth downside is that, certainly as currently engineered, the internet enables massive levels of fraud and information theft.

It isn't clear in general how to balance all the effects and contingencies, and arrive at a clear conclusion of whether more computerisation is beneficial or not.

It's also worth noting that tech fetishism primarily exists amongst liberals because they view the computer as an unwaged worker under their total control, which is an alternative to paying a waged worker with an independent mind.

There is often an absence of any grand moral background - the agenda nowadays is usually simply to attack workers and reduce the wage bill, almost regardless of anything else.

This is different from when computerisation first began in the 60s, when employment was full, it was largely seen as a way of releasing workers into less routine employment and (by improving labour productivity) increasing wage rates and reducing working hours.

In reality today, computerisation is likely to result in the sack of government workers, an enlarged reserve of unemployed, and no reduction in any point-of-use charges for government services. If anything is saved for the "taxpayer", it will be conveyed on as tax cuts only for the rich, not for the taxpaying masses.